# How do I pass a variable to a controller function from the view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, routes, parameter-passing

I have a user controller with an agentexport function, which is supposed to download an excell spreadsheet. Below is the function:

```
  function agentexport($agentName) {
    if($this->isAdmin() == TRUE) {
        $this->loadThis();
    }
    else {
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // Gets all the data using agent name
        $data = $this->excel_model->getdatabyname($agentname);

        //print_r($data);
        //die;

        $this->excel->stream('crosstown.xls', $data);
     }
}
```

In my views I am trying to execute the above function with the following button:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url().'agentexport/'.$record->agentName; ?>" title="Download Sheet><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Download Sheet</a>
```

The above button is meant to download the spreadsheet right away. 
The url is defined in my routes as :

```
$route['agentexport'] = "user/agentexport";
```

Did I define my route the right way ? When I click on the route I get the following url 
 http://www.XXXXX.com/John%20Grisham.
As you can see, the name is appended at the end of the url but the page shows a 404. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal opinion here, but I don't think there's any strong reason to use a route. If nothing else, the following will be a good experiment to see if the `$route` definition is the problem.

1. Delete the `$route` you have been using for 'agentexport'.
2. Change the link to

`<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="<?= base_url('user/agentexport/'.$record->agentName); ?>" title="Download Sheet"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Download Sheet</a>`

To test that the link works and is passing the value, use the following version of `agentexport`

```
public function agentexport($agentName)
{
    echo $agentName;
    //or alternately
    //var_dump($agentName);
}
```

It is assumed that you verified `$agentName` is a usable value *before* you used it in the link. If the above shows you a value, then you know the `$route` was the problem.

You can experiment to find a `$route`, but `$route['agentexport/(:any)'] = 'user/agentexport/$1';` **should** work. If you're going to switch back to using a route don't forget to revert the link code. I'd write it like this, where the URI is passed as an argument to `base_url`.

`<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="<?= base_url('agentexport/'.$record->agentName); ?>" title="Download Sheet"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Download Sheet</a>`

If you find a route that works - and using a route is what you really, really want - then restore the code in `agentexport` to what you actually need. But again, I don't see any strong reason to obfuscate the link's URL.

Comment: Thanks so much. Exactly what I was aking.

Answer (score 0):

If, from the view, you're pointing to `/controller_name/method/agent_name` (which is basically what you're doing after the route "translation", all  you need to do is pick the agent name from the URI using the URL helper (remember to load it beforehand)

```
$user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

The above will take whatever is in the third segment of the URI (`agent_name` in my example) and assign it to the `$user_id` variable.
Remember that whatever is possible to be manipulated by the user cannot be trusted, so you need to sanitize `$user_id` and make sure that the user requesting the file is allowed to access it

Comment: Thanks that helps. Wondering if my route is well defined though. Should I define it like $route['agentexport/:any'] = "user/agentexport";  or $route['agentexport'] = "user/agentexport?:any";    ?

Comment: If you must use routes (instead of just linking to `user/agentexport`) you should do as specified in the CI manual. `$route['agentexport/(:any)'] = 'user/agentexport/$1';` so that the parameter is passed as a variable to the function. I'm not sure if you will encounter issues by having the matched pattern (agentexport) and the destination route to be the same (never tried it that way) though...

Comment: For some reason I cannot access the agentname inside the controller function. I have tried print_r  and echo

Comment: can you `print "<pre>".print_r($this->uri->segment(3), true)."</pre>";` and share the output?

Comment: First of all my url of the link is not working. Do you see any error between my routes definition and the link ? I am trying to even not have a route but just have the function link to user/agentexport . How do I do this by passing the agent_name as a parameter to the controller function ?

Comment: I just used the route definition $route['agentexport/:any'] = "user/agentexport/:any". But the print_r statement does not  put out anything. Maybe I need to rephrase the question.

Comment: I believe you may be "confusing" the CodeIgniter routing by using the same name in the method and in the route (basically, routes attempt to match something in the URI and re-route to some place else.. if the destination has the same name, CI may misbehave)... try this: deactivate the route (comment it out) and try going directly to /user/agentexport/agent_name and see if you can extract the agent name using the URL helper (which you need to load beforehand)